# ¿Cómo prevenir Timeouts?

Tags: javascript, timeout

¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando de click en un boton, inicie el timeout, pero que al presionar de nuevo algun otro boton, elimine el timeout si no se ha completado?

```js
 function timeout(number) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`timeout ${number}`);
    }, 1000);
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="timeout(1)"> myButton1 </button>
<button onclick="timeout(2)"> myButton2 </button>
```

O sea, si presiono 3 veces consecutivas con menos de 1 segundo entre cada 1, solamente se ejecutaria el timeout 1 sola vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el siguiente codigo, se guarda el id del ultimo proceso de timeout, con este id se puede detener el proceso anterior usando clearTimeout()

```
 lastTimeout=0;

 function timeout(number) {
    if (lastTimeout){
      clearTimeout(lastTimeout);
    }
    lastTimeout=setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`timeout ${number}`);
    }, 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

La función `clearTimeout()` te permite pasarle el id del timeout que has creado previamente con setTimeout para cancelarlo.

El siguiente código te permite quedarte solamente con el último timeout sin importar cuantas veces o en cuales botones se haya hecho el clic

```js
let lastTimeout;

function timeout(number) {
    clearTimeout(lastTimeout);
    
    lastTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`timeout ${number}`);
    }, 1000);
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="timeout(1)"> myButton1 </button>
<button onclick="timeout(2)"> myButton2 </button>
```